# Tails and Qubes/Whonix?

Tags: tails, tor-install, whonix, qubes

I’m just trying to learn about Tails and Qubes/Whonix. What gives you the most security and anonymously online? Tails on its own or Qubes with Whonix or Tails, Qubes and Whonix all three together? And why? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: What’s your goal here? Are you dedicating a computer to this? Or do you need to only run it temporarily on a computer you share with other work? Neither is really going to give you more security or anonymity than the other, but which you should use depends on your use case.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Comparison_with_Others